# Cohomology of the classifying space of some Super Lie group

Tags: reference-request, at.algebraic-topology, dg.differential-geometry, supermanifolds

Are there any papers on the cohomology of the classifying space of the general linear supergroup $GL(n, m)$ or unitary supergroup $U(n, m)$?

I know basically nothing about supergeometry. It seems that in my situation I just need to know the cohomology of the classifying spaces of the supergroups mentioned above. When I google for this topic, I basically found nothing, but other information seems to imply that ordinary cohomology theory (for example, singular or de Rham) cannot detect the superdifferentiable structure of supermanifolds, so some cohomology theories for supermanifolds were invented (I know there are different classes of supermanifolds, but I don't the groups or its classifying spaces belong to which class). Thus, as a start, I think I need to know the ordinary cohomology of $BGL(n, m)$ and $BU(n, m)$ (if it exists).

Thanks.

Comment: The usual definition of B first takes the underlying space of GL(n,m), which only sees the underlying ordinary manifold of GL(n,m).  Thus the classifying space of the super Lie group GL(n,m) is the same as the classifying space of its underlying ordinary Lie group.

Comment: I see.  So can I say classifying complex supervector bundle is just the same as classifying its underlying complex vector bundle？If this is true, then it's interesting that the super structure is lost when doing classification.

Comment: If you use the traditional definition of a classifying space, you don't see the odd direction.  But one could consider many other notions of classifying spaces, with different universal properties.  For example, one could argue that the right notion of a classifying space in supergeometry is a stack of spaces on the site of superpoints (i.e., R^{0|n}), whose value on R^{0|n} is the classifying space of Hom(R^{0|n},G).  One can then extract nontrivial spaces from such a stack by taking various homotopy colimits, which will detect a significant part of the odd direction.

Comment: A category where one can build $BG$ for a Lie supergroup $G$ would be the site of simplicial presheaves on the category of supermanifolds (with the Grothendieck topology coming from open covers). However, if one localizes this category at $\mathbb{R}^{1|0}$ one loses all the odd directions and gets the category of simplicial presheaves on manifolds localized at $\mathbb{R}$. This category is equivalent to the homotopy category of topological spaces. (cont.)

Comment: @DmitriPavlov Can you elaborate on how to produce nontrivial spaces? $\mathrm{Hom}(\mathbb{R}^{0|n}, G)_0$ is still homotopy equivalent to $G_0$. I can only think of extracting the Thom space of $(TG)_1 \rightarrow G_0$ by restricting to some sort of proper morphisms. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @ruediger: It is not difficult to actually classify _all_ possible classifying space (or realization) functors.  Such a functor should be a homotopy cocontinuous functor from simplicial presheaves on supermanifolds to spaces.  This amounts to assigning a space to every R^{m|n} (functorially with respect to morphisms of supermanifolds) in such a way that any Čech cover is mapped to a weak equivalence of spaces.  Sending everything to a point gives you the usual realization, other choices give more interesting results.

Comment: @DmitriPavlov Can you introduce a reference for your second comment? I am very in need to understand the classifying space for Lie supergroup. Also, there could be different notions of classifying space for supergroups then. Which one is "the one" or this is very context-dependent? Furthermore, what you mean by a significant part of odd directions? How can we get all of the information in odd direction? Thanks, your comment is the only thing I could find about this subject ...

Comment: @QGravity: The underlying philosophy of presenting supergeometric objects as presheaves on the site of superpoints is explained in Sachse's _[A Categorical Formulation of Superalgebra and Supergeometry](http://arxiv.org/abs/0802.4067)_.  See also the nLab article [superpoint](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/superpoint) and links therein.

Comment: @DmitriPavlov thanks a lot, this article seems to be exactly what I was looking for.